# IBM Worklight - securityTest="wl_unprotected" causes adapter to not work

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am calling a public adapter procedure and have assigned `securityTest="wl_unprotected"` to it. If I call the procedure via URL, it works fine, but when calling from device/app then it's not working...

What could be the reason?

Comment: What is the nature of the procedure you're using this security test on? Usually this security test is used to protect adapter procedures that should be publicly accessible without any authentication requirements.

Comment: Yes, I want it to be publicly accessible. In other words, without user's login. Is there something i have to set in the authenticationConfig.xml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed by email, the issue is not in the way the adapter procedure is being setup in the adapter XML, but IMO in the way the client-side code is handling it.

This question is not so fit to Stackoverflow...